# Dealing with the Multiindex headers dataFrame - Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe which looks like this. In the header, it have 2 lines of header, like one heading in row 1 cover  5 subheaddings in row 2.

```html
      Toneladas planta, ton  
  Fecha  Fecha  Ton  SAG1 Ton1
1_2017 1/1/2017 827 1309 2195
1_2017 1/2/2017 913 1343 2222
1_2017 1/3/2017 887 1435 2272
1_2017 1/4/2017 877 1388 2151
1_2017 1/5/2017 900 1236 2177
1_2017 1/6/2017 797 1201 2012
1_2017 1/7/2017 751 1215 2109
1_2017 1/8/2017 851 1241 2109
1_2017 1/9/2017 917 1408 2303
1_2017 1/10/2017 864 1529 2414
1_2017 1/11/2017 911 1560 2383
```

[image: Dataframe]

The values in row 2 are of value to me. But when i am applying functions on the data frame, it is unable to identify the row 2 headers and gives false values. For example: df.info() like functions, gives the wrong values.

I would like to know, if there is a way, i can either mix the two headers to one, in a way that that row 1 becomes the prefix and row 2 as suffix of the shares heading.

Like :
Toneladas planta, ton
Fecha Fecha

becomes:
Toneladas planta, ton Fecha    Toneladas planta, ton Fecha

as otherwise its too difficult to work with the dataframe.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Given the following Excel Sheet:

[image]

- Just specify the header row with the `header` parameter, and `usecols` to get the correct columns

```py
df = pd.read_excel('file.xlsx', header=3, usecols='A:E')

  Fecha    Fecha.1    Ton SAG1     Ton SAG2  Ton  Planta
 1_2017 2017-01-01  826.555503  1308.834944  2194.939490
 1_2017 2017-01-02  912.653670  1343.165048  2221.776328
 1_2017 2017-01-03  886.866000  1434.944123  2272.475950
 1_2017 2017-01-04  877.476604  1388.086279  2150.790596
 1_2017 2017-01-05  900.459985  1236.101284  2177.152583
```